# Credit card payment directly to ACH deposit

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

We are currently using stripe for our app's licensing and service fee(s) however we'd like to extend the ability to accept credit cards to our users. Every user of ours has customers who access their invoices through our app.

The flow would basically entail our users providing checking account and routing information so that when they enable payment processing for their customers, those payments are deposited directly into their account after our app collects a small convenience fee.

I've looked at multiple service providers and scoured their API documentation but I've yet to find a single (or even the combination of two) providers who can handle this. The key is we don't want to hold the money, we simply want to charge our fee and pass the rest along minus any processing fee associated with the actual payment processor.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many people try to do this and have had many arguments with technical people about why you don't want to do this.  So let's break this down:

**Technical**

It seems like a no-brainer way to make money: you have customers, you take card payments on their behalf (keeping a percentage for yourself), and then they get the rest of the money.  Now you need to do one of 2 things:

1. Collect all the bank transfer information from the customer and write back-end processes to transfer money after deducting fees and the company's percentage.

It doesn't seem to hard and maybe you make it happen.  Then the business realizes that there is no non-repudiation built into the system.  How do you audit what the system thinks it transferred to your customer's bank against what was actually deposited in the bank?  How do you handle refunding charges your customer disputes? And so on and so forth...

2. Realizing that it would take your team some effort to build, stabilize, and support the system you look for the payment processor to do it all for you.  Stripe, for example, has something called Managed Accounts.  So you think, "Awesome, we'll just have Stripe handle it!"  Everything is great, or so you thought.....

**Business**

The business side realizes, often too late one or more of the following:

1. This is very expensive to develop in-house.  If there has been investment in development they have to decide if they want to drop the use of the system or fully commit to developing all necessary features to support the accounting and non-repudiation features.  (Usually they bail...)
2. Taking the third party route, all goes well for a while.  Suddenly there is a major incident of credit card fraud for one of your customers. The business suddenly learns that they are liable for chargebacks or shady business practices of their customers because your customer's bank account doesn't have the funds to cover a large chargeback.  No one asked about the liability up-front because they didn't fully understand that card issuers have made sure they have absolutely zero risk in this game.  (This is why they'll issue a credit card to your dog if you ask nicely.)

If the cost of development didn't make the business bail, the big bad word LIABILITY usually makes them run for the hills.

**Conclusion**

From a technical perspective, this is a quick-win that seems like a cash cow.

From a business perspective, not so much.

Usually what business do is become a reseller of payment services.  This usually entails providing their own on-boarding systems to help sign customers up and go through the vetting process.  This also is generally combined with help in getting the merchant enabled to process cards.  In return, the reseller gets a small percentage of the processing fees and no liability for the merchant's chargebacks; instead, the liability is fully on the merchant.

Have fun with this one!